# how to display the output after the save button or refresh permanently

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have the following code below.

how to display the output after the save button or refresh permanently

```
<apex:page id="pageid" standardController="Product_and_Services__c"   >
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js"/>

 <apex:form id="formid">
   <script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
   document.getElementById("myid").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid1").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("myid2").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("myid3").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("addbutton").style.visibility="visible";
}
function test1(){
   document.getElementById("myid").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("myid1").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid2").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("myid3").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("addbutton").style.visibility="hidden";
}
function test12(){
    document.getElementById("myid").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid1").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("myid2").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("myid3").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("addbutton").style.visibility="hidden";

}
function test2(){
  document.getElementById("myid").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid1").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("myid2").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid3").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("addbutton").style.visibility="hidden";

}
function test3(){
  document.getElementById("myid").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid1").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("myid2").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("myid3").style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById("addbutton").style.visibility="visible";

}





</script>

 <apex:pageBlock id="pbid" >
  <div id="myid" style="visibility:visible">
 <apex:dataTable id="selected1" value="{!Product_and_Services__c}" var="product" cellPadding="1" border="0" bgcolor="White" style="width:65%; font-family: Helvetica">

   <apex:column >
     Product Line Item :     
   </apex:column>   
   <apex:column id="cid">  
     <apex:inputField id="prodid" value="{!product.Product_Line_Item_1__c} " />   
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
      Screening:
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:inputField value="{!product.Product_Screening1__c}" /> 
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
    <apex:commandButton value="Add" onclick="test()" rerender="selected"  />
   </apex:column>

 </apex:dataTable>
 </div>

  <div id="myid1" style="visibility:hidden">
  <apex:dataTable id="selected" value="{!Product_and_Services__c}" var="product" cellPadding="15" border="0" bgcolor="White" style="width:35%; font-family: Helvetica">

     <apex:column >
        Product Line Item : 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column id="cid1">
      <apex:outputField value="{!product.Product_Line_Item_1__c}" /> 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       Screening:
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       <apex:outputField value="{!product.Product_Screening1__c}"  /> 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       <apex:commandButton value="X" onclick="test1()" rerender="selected1"  />
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       <div id="addbutton" >
       <apex:commandButton value="Add" onclick="test12()"  rerender="selected2" />
        </div>
     </apex:column>

  </apex:dataTable>
  </div>


  <div id="myid2" style="visibility:hidden">
 <apex:dataTable id="selected2" value="{!Product_and_Services__c}" var="product" cellPadding="1" border="0" bgcolor="White" style="width:65%; font-family: Helvetica">

   <apex:column >
     Product Line Item :     
   </apex:column>   
   <apex:column id="cid2">  
     <apex:inputField id="prodid2" value="{!product.Product_Line_Items_2__c} " />   
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
      Screening:
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:inputField value="{!product.Product_Screening2__c}" /> 
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column >
     <apex:commandButton value="Add" onclick="test2()" rerender="selected3"  /> 
   </apex:column>

 </apex:dataTable>
 </div>

  <div id="myid3" style="visibility:hidden">
  <apex:dataTable id="selected3" value="{!Product_and_Services__c}" var="product" cellPadding="15" border="0" bgcolor="White" style="width:35%; font-family: Helvetica">

     <apex:column >
        Product Line Item : 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column id="cid3">
      <apex:outputField value="{!product.Product_Line_Items_2__c}" /> 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       Screening:
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       <apex:outputField value="{!product.Product_Screening2__c}"  /> 
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column >
       <apex:commandButton value="X" onclick="test3()" rerender="selected"  />
     </apex:column>

  </apex:dataTable>
  </div>
    <apex:facet name="footer" >
    <apex:commandLink action="{!save}" value="Save" styleClass="btn" onclick="test2()"   target="_blank" style="float:right; padding:4px;width:15%; height: 15px;color: white;background: #7DB4E5"/>
    </apex:facet> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The output as follows. Hence after I click the save button or refresh the page the page refreshes and starts with the input. I would like to make it as the output read only field.

Is there a way by using it with javascript to accomplish that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to the [Inline edit support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm).

Because of the standard controller you can easily use the `save` method without controller. And you can just use inline editing with it. So all fields are displayed as non-editable. After double-clicking on any field with `inlineEditSupport` it will be editable. Something like this:

```visualforce
<apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton id="saveButton" action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Product_and_Services__c.Product_Line_Item_1__c}">
            <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton"/>
        </apex:outputField> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, I tried using that however it refreshes the entire page and the field doesn't get updated.